# Resolve Function Address with PE Export Table

Tags: .net, dll, mapping, dllexport, portable-executable

Can anyone explain me how to properly obtain a function address from a PE image and then call that function with a delegate?
I found a good piece code googling around that loads exports from a DLL library, but it only get function names out of it... so I modified it as follows:

```
[DllImport("ImageHlp", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern bool MapAndLoad(string imageName, string dllPath, out LOADED_IMAGE loadedImage, bool dotDll, bool readOnly);

public static IntPtr CustomGetProcAddress(string modulePath, string moduleProc)
{
    LOADED_IMAGE loadedImage;

    if (MapAndLoad(modulePath, null, out loadedImage, true, true))
        return GetAddr(loadedImage, moduleProc);
    else
        return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private static IntPtr GetAddr(LOADED_IMAGE loadedImage, string moduleProc)
{
    var hMod = (void*)loadedImage.MappedAddress;

    if (hMod != null)
    {
        uint size;
        var pExportDir = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)ImageDirectoryEntryToData(
            (void*)loadedImage.MappedAddress,
            false,
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT,
            out size);

        uint* pFuncNames = (uint*)RvaToVa(loadedImage, pExportDir->AddressOfNames);
        ushort* pFuncOrdinals = (ushort*)RvaToVa(loadedImage, pExportDir->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
        uint* pFuncAddr = (uint*)RvaToVa(loadedImage, pExportDir->AddressOfFunctions);

        for (uint i = 0; i < pExportDir->NumberOfNames; i++)
        {
            uint funcNameRva = pFuncNames[i];

            if (funcNameRva != 0)
            {
                char* funcName = (char*)RvaToVa(loadedImage, funcNameRva);
                string name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)funcName);
                _exports.Add(name);

                if (name == wantedFunction)
                    return addr = new IntPtr(*(uint*)(pFuncAddr + (*pFuncOrdinals * 4)));
            }
        }
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

I'm sure I'm quote close to the solution... but I always get AccessViolationException (when I use wrong pointers) or InvalidFunctionPointerInDelegate and PInvokeStackImbalance (when I try to cast the pointer to a delegate using Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer and then execute it).
I tried everything but I can't make it work (I already pulled out the correct address of the function I'm looking for using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress... so I can compare the results, but I don't want to use those functions).

[EDIT] I found another example, but I'm not sure it can do what I'm looking for:
[http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/39366-c-loadlibary-from-byte/page_*k*_bb2fe024f8a71424996db6d9af08c1fc_*settingNewSkin*_19](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/39366-c-loadlibary-from-byte/page__k__bb2fe024f8a71424996db6d9af08c1fc__settingNewSkin__19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.  The `MapAndLoad` and function from the `ImageHlp` library only loads a PE file into memory as a data file so it can be examined.  It does not run through all of the logic of the Windows loader does when it loads a DLL to make it executable (RVA fixups, etc.).

If you want to load a DLL, find a function by name, and get an callable pointer to it, you use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  Those functions where designed to do exactly what you are looking trying to do.

Comment: That's the problem... I don't want to use GetProcAddress and LoadLibrary. I know it's easy to find a function address by name using it... but it's not what I'm looking for. I saw a lot of C/C++ programs doing that, but I can't reproduce it in .NET... any alternative? Like mh... reading the DLL from memory?

Comment: @Zarathos - Then you have to is re-write all the logic that the Windows loader does when it loads a DLL - good luck on that.  I don't know why you are averse to using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress (they do work fine in .NET - I've used them myself).  If this is a learning experience then knock yourself out; if this is production code then use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said previously, the `MapAndLoad` function is just loading the file as data - the memory page it's loaded into will non-executable, and so trying to jump to a location within this memory will almost certainly not work. You're going to need a significantly more complex method if you want to get around using `LoadLibrary` - but the first step will be ensuring that  the executable sections of the PE file are loaded into executable memory (followed by implementing all of the other functionality of the Windows Loader!) I've never attempted this, but from what I can see on a brief search there are numerous issues associated with getting around issues such as Windows DEP (data execution prevention).